# Can I make Emailing an address that forwards back to me appear in the inbox?

Tags: gmail

I have a Gmail address that's my primary email.  I have a couple short email addresses on my own domain that I have set to forward to the Gmail account.

For various reasons, I like to email these addresses from my Gmail account (which will then forward back to myself). The frustration is, these emails do not show up in my inbox - only the "All Mail" tab.

There's a filter to "skip the inbox".
Why can't there be one for "put it in the inbox"?

Comment: I'm confused. If your forwarding emails from your other email addresses (not gmail), then what's the problem? Forwarded emails should always get thrown to your gmail account.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "get thrown to.." but the emails DO get forwarded to the account, but for some reason skip the inbox

Comment: Oh. I see. How are you forwarding them to your inbox. Are you doing it through gmail or are you having the other accounts forward to your gmail account?

Comment: I have a couple short email addresses on my own domain that I have set to forward to the gmail acct.

Comment: That's odd. Now I see why you asked this question. Usually forwarded emails get sent straight to the inbox. Odd.

Comment: Just confirmed gmail acts the same way for my friend too.  I think it has to do with the "sending" address being the same as the "recieving" address, even with the 'middle-man'

Comment: What are your POP and IMAP settings? POP download's second settings should say "Keep Gmail's copy in the Inbox".

Comment: yup, thats how its set - normal out of the box configuration.  Thank you for talking this through with me, but on the odd chance you didn't notice, the problem has been solved (below), if not the reason.

Comment: I was aware that it was solved. I was just a first confused as to how this occurred. (As I have never had such a problem, but I did stop using gmail). Then I was curious as to what caused this, if there was a setting. You would think gmail would not be able to tell the difference between forwarded email and "actual" email. I guess it's just one of those weird things about Gmail. Google should really fix that. Anyway, thanks for giving me all the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As one option, you could make sure that your email filter turns on "Never send it to Spam" and "Always mark it as Important".

[image: No Spam, Mark Important]

In your Inbox setting, you can "Override filters" and always include Important emails in the inbox.

[image: Override Filter, Include Important]

I don't have a way to test this suggestion, but could you give me feedback as to whether this worked for you?

Comment: I probably should have experimented with that stuff some more before posting.  It seems to have worked.  I think it was the mark as important option that fixed it for me!  Thanks!

Comment: I have since noticed a somewhat annoying consequence of this. Now ALL of my sent mail appears at the top of my inbox :-/

Comment: Your filter needs to include **only** the from addresses where you would like to see this behavior. The place where you designate from is the screen just prior to designating `Always mark as important`